# XHR Date header not being applied in WindowsPhone 8 request

Tags: windows-phone-8, cordova, xmlhttprequest, request-headers

I am communicating with a third party service via XHR (cannot use ajax as I need to send as ArrayBuffer).  I had a bunch of problems getting this to work under WP8 but have finally gotten a connection (always worked fine under android and iOS (phonegap)).  The problem I have is that I need to send through a couple of specific headers for authentication.  I am sending this through as:

```
 xhr.open("POST", url, true);
 xhr.timeout = 30000;

 xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-Type",contentType+"; boundary=" + boundary);
 xhr.setRequestHeader("Accept","application/json; charset=utf-8");

 xhr.setRequestHeader("Authorization",auth);
 xhr.setRequestHeader("Date",todayString);                  

 xhr.send(bodyBuf);
```

In essence this works fine other than: the 'Date' header is never received.  I constantly get back a response of 'Date header required'.  I know that the actual connection is not something that you will be able to advise on, however I am wondering if anyone has encountered this before?  Is everyone else able to set the xhr 'Date' header in WP8 which would imply that something is different in my code/setup or if anyone has any ideas.

btw, I am getting the same result when testing through the emulator and via an HTC it is not specific to a single device. but to the WP8 platform

Thanks,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have found that this is a known problem.  the ie httpwebrequest does not contain a 'Date' header so this can never be set.  In order to do this, I have had to make a WP plugin to use the recently added mobile-httpclient code, which can set the 'Date' header.